# Canvas save pixels drawn out of view artifacting

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm using the html5 canvas and javascript to draw some stuff on the screen. However as what i'm drawing will sometimes be large, I have a panning function.

To problem is that when the drawing goes off-screen on either the top or left part, I get a strange artifact.
[image: artifact]

I'm using the `toDataURL()` function to save the data drawn, and redrawing it as an image using `drawImage()`.

The app can be found [here](http://www.r4vang3r.net/wp-content/citygen/l-system_v11/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you're draggin it "lower" than the rendering boundary.

```
 =====================
 emtpy with artifacts
 empty with artifacts
 _____________________________
 start of your canvas drawing
```

since the empty space doesn't get filled up with a solid color, it keeps it as it was in the buffer.

Just detect the edge of your drawing pane, and fill up rest of visible viewport with a fillrect when drawing lower then view port after drag.

Comment: Is there a way to change the rendering boundary? I would like the canvas to be bigger then the screen but still centered.

Comment: Actually moving the html element itself works fine though.